# Redux how to use "compose" with Typescript

Tags: typescript, redux

I have a bit issue with using compose function in Typescript, I always receive errors. The type definition in .d.ts is also quite confusing. For example:

```
type Props = { t: number }; 
const foo = (props: {}) => <div {...props} />;
const moo = (props: Props) => <div {...props} />;
const bar = (props: Props) => <div {...props} />;
const Dar = compose(foo, moo)(bar);

const Test = () => <Dar />;
```

Has several problems. It is complaining that "bar" does not have "foo" parameter (which it actually has).

Also, I cannot use  since Dar is evaluated to JSX.Element not stateless function. Any IDEA with possible example of how to use compose in Typescript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The inference of TypeScript works from left to right, a generic `compose` function composes functions from right to left, and it could lead to wrong types.

You can use a composition function which composes from left to right, like [flow](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/function.ts.html#flow-function).

Answer (score 0):

`compose` is a function that combines two functions assuming the output type of the first function matches the input type of the second function.

`const compose = (f,g) => x => f(g(x))`

So what you're saying in your compose line is that you want to apply `bar` (which is a function from `Props` to `JSX.Element`) as an argument to `moo` which is also a function from `Props` to `JSX.Element` and then take the result of that and apply it to `foo`.

> The problem is that `moo` doesn't accept a function from `Props` to `JSX.Element`, it accepts `Props`

If you want to return a "stateless function" you'll need to use this template to tell Typescript that's what you want

```
const bar: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (x: Props) => <div {...props} />;
```